# How to load properties file in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

So I'm trying to add some ability to my project to allow user-defined properties in my deployment artifact - a simple key:value .properties file.  I place the service.properties file in

```
war/WEB-INF/my-service.properties
```

And in my ServiceImpl.java constructor I have the following:

```
String propertiesFileName = "my-service.properties"; 

URL propertyURL = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(propertiesFileName);
URL propertyURL2 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(propertiesFileName);
URL propertyURL3 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( "WEB-INF/" + propertiesFileName);
URL propertyURL6 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(
       "E:/Projects/eclipse-workspace/projectName/war/WEB-INF/" + propertiesFileName);
```

All instances of Property URL are null.  I know I'm missing something absolutely obvious, but I need a second pair of eyes.  Regards.

EDIT:

Ah, it seems I was confused as the default GAE project creates a logging.properties file in /war.  From the [Google App Engine documentation:](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Logging)

*The App Engine Java SDK includes a template logging.properties file, in the appengine-java-sdk/config/user/ directory. To use it, copy the file to your WEB-INF/classes directory (or elsewhere in the WAR), then the system property java.util.logging.config.file to "WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties" (or whichever path you choose, relative to the application root). You can set system properties in the appengine-web.xml file, as follows:*

Comment: I assume it is a typo in your question rather than your app, but you state that your file is called "service.properties" yet propertiesFileName is set to "my-service.properties"!

Comment: @Todd:  Yes, it's a typo, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try putting the service.properties in WEB-INF/classes.  Then it should be accessible just with :

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/filename.properties");
```

Comment: Do you know why for me I needed to remove the "/" at the start of the path for it to work?

Comment: I'm receiving an NPE. I'm attempting to access the file (*kotlin/ webapp/WEB-INF/fileName.json*) from my class (*kotlin/ClassName*) `val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(this.javaClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/coinverse-media-staging-firebase-config.json"))`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/838103/mike) mentioned in his comment to [jsight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1432/jsight)s answer, it worked for me if I used

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.properties");
```

(removed the first slash) after placing the file in WEB-INF/classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you will need is something like this:

String filePath = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/views/") + "/" + mav.getViewName() + ".vm";
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);

I get the servletContext from spring: @Autowire ServletContext.