# Reading a "properties" file

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, rest, resteasy

I have a Rest service using Resteasy (running on top of Appengine), with the following psuedo code:

```
@Path("/service")
public class MyService {
  @GET
  @Path("/start")
  public Response startService() {
     // Need to read properties file here.
     // like: servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config.properties")
  }
}
```

However its obvious that the servlet context cannot be accessed here.

And code like:

```
 InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config.properties");
```

Can't be executed within the Appengine environment.

**EDIT:**

I have tried doing it with Spring like:

**appContext.xml**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="/WEB-INF/auth.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Then, put this on the actual class fields:

```
@Path("/service")
public MyService{
    @Autowired
    @Value("${myservice.userid}")
    private String username;
    @Autowired
    @Value("${myservice.passwd}")
    private String password;
 // Code omitted
}
```

However, part of the code of the `MyService` complains because the `username` and `password` was not "injected", I mean its empty although its on the `auth.properties` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RESTEasy you can easily inject Servlet context via @Context annotation: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.1.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_Context

Examples can be found here: [Rest easy and init params - how to access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434667/rest-easy-and-init-params-how-to-access)

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you put the file in `/WEB-INF/classes/` (which, importantly, is on the classpath), specifying config.properties as a file at the top-level.

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
```

See this similar question: [How to load properties file in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362545/how-to-load-properties-file-in-google-app-engine)

**Edit**: Now you've edited, I'll respond & answer the Spring-related question. So, put the auth.properties into /WEB-INF/classes/ , and then specify classpath as follows.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:auth.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I can't put the properties file in WEB-INF folder?

Comment: No, not with that method, because WEB-INF isn't on the classpath. That method, `getResourceAsStream(..)`, looks on the classpath. If you're stuck as to how to get it into your classpath, you could always put it in your source folder, and let `javac` send it there for you.

Comment: Same problem, the username and password is not injected

Comment: hmm, a couple of wild guesses: do you have a <context:component-scan ... /> in your Spring config? If you don't it might not be processing the annotations. Or, perhaps the properties processing fails before it gets to the correct point. This seems like a Spring problem - suggest you rephrase your question with more info, into a new question. The scope has changed a lot since my first answer! Good luck