# How do I read a file in Google App Engine (JAVA)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have to authorize my server to Firebase for the Firebase SDK. But unfortunately I can't read the credentials.json file. I have put my service.json file into my WEB-INF folder.

I have added this to my appengine-web.xml file:

```
<resource-files>
    <include path="/service.json"/>
</resource-files>
```

And I am trying to read the file with this code:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setServiceAccount(ServletServletContext.class.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/service.json"))
```

But when I try to read the file I get a NullPointerException.

This is my whole class:

```
@Api(
  name = "myApi",
version = "v1",
namespace = @ApiNamespace(
ownerDomain = "backend",
ownerName = "backend",
packagePath=""
  )
)
public class MyEndpoint {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyEndpoint.class.getName());
private String uid;

@ApiMethod(name = "signup")
public MyBean signup(@Named("token")String token)
{
    uid = "empty";
    uid = "init";

    log.info(new File(getClass().getResource("/WEB-INF/service.json").toString()).exists()+"");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setServiceAccount(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/service.json"))
                .setDatabaseUrl("url")
                .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    uid = "initialized";

    log.severe("initialized");
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(token)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken decodedToken) {uid = decodedToken.getUid();
                    }
            });

    MyBean b = new MyBean();
    if(!uid.equals(""))
        b.setData(uid);
    // else
    // b.setData("failed");

    return b;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There is no need to modify appengine-web.xml. How do you read the file?

Comment: When I am using a FileInputStream to read this file I am getting a access denied, but then I have looked it up and someone said I should do it like this, but with this code I am just getting NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: There are many questions on StackOverflow that explain how to read a static file on App Engine. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362545/how-to-load-properties-file-in-google-app-engine?rq=1

Comment: I have tried the answer, but it is still not working. Where do I have to put the file? Currently I got it in my WEB-INF folder and what is the path to this file?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340653/file-path-to-resource-in-our-war-web-inf-folder

Comment: I don't have the method getContext() in my class.
I want to do that in a Endpoint class if that is important.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/service.json");
```

Comment: I am still getting NullPointerExceptions with this solutions

Comment: NullPointerException should point to specific line of code. Which one?

Comment: setServiceAccount(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/service.json"))
this one

Comment: Are you using it in the right context? What class contains this method?

Comment: I have added my whole class to my question if this helps.

Comment: You log statement with `new File` does not make sense.

Comment: I just tried something out and didn't delete it yet.

Comment: Ok I have tried something to create the inputstream with a string and now it says I can only use Firebase on a backend. So my question is, can I use firebase with Endpoints?

Comment: Your `/WEB-INF/` is on your backend. And yes, you can only use it on the backend. There is no need to call this method within a bean.

Comment: So if I want to develop my backend with google app engine I have to call the endpoint with my app and the endpoint is communicating with a servlet or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Your endpoint is your backend/servlet. You just need to restructure your code, where no server-side code is included in entities that are shared with the client.

Comment: Where do I have to put the code, because I put it in a private method, which I am calling in the apimethod, but it is still not working. Could you tell me where I have to put the code?

Comment: Ok I have found the problem. I had to add manual-scaling to my xml file.

Comment: @ReasoN How is manual-scaling related to including *.json* files? may you provide details on the code for manual scaling and where you implemented it.

Comment: @ReasoN I don't think manual scaling is related as I attempted to add the stream path solution and ran it locally in my IDE and got the NPE.

Comment: I don’t know. It’s just that app engine didn’t allow that at the time I tried doing it. Maybe they changed it, but I don’t know.